# Django ORM: count related objects with a feature

Tags: python, django, aggregate, django-queryset

Lets say we have **House** and **Room** models. 
Each **house** has several **rooms** and each **room** has a number of **beds**.

How to select number of bedrooms in each **house**? All **houses** must appear in the result.

Model classes:

```
class House(models.Model):
    pass

class Room(models.Model):
    house = models.ForeignKey('House')
    beds = models.IntegerField()
```

I tried:

```
House.objects.filter(room__beds__gt=0).annotate(bedrooms=Count('room'))
```

But this solution does not contain houses without bedrooms.

I prefer not to use pure SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add houses without bedrooms to your query like this:

```
from itertools import chain
from django.db.models import Q, Count

qs = House.objects.all()
q = {'room__beds__gt': 0}
qs_with = qs.filter(Q(**q)).annotate(bedrooms=Count('room'))
qs_without = qs.filter(~Q(**q)).extra(select={'bedrooms': 0})
qs_all = chain(qs_with, qs_without)
```

Comment: Perfect! I can use queryset filtering before calculating the bedrooms.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try.

```
House.objects.extra(select={
        "bedrooms": "SELECT count(*) FROM YOURAPP_room WHERE house_id=YOURAPP_house.id AND beds > 0"})
```

Comment: I prefer not to use pure SQL. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I don't think this works in a single query without SQL.

Comment: This solution is practically unusable. This query takes 14 mins to load for 1k ``House`` and 100k ``Room`` records. While filtering by ``room__beds__gt=0`` and annotating takes 5 seconds.

Comment: This SQL query ignores ``filter()`` applied before ``extra()`` call.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `related_name` to your house field in Room class. It will look like this:

```
house = models.ForeignKey('House', related_name='rooms')
```

then you can access `Room` objects from `House` objects.

Now, if `h1` is an object of `House` you can do something like this..

```
rooms_total = 0

for room in h1.rooms.all():
  rooms_total += room.beds
```

Comment: I need to do this in a single query. This means you have to use Django Queryset API, no custom Python code can be used.

Comment: You don't have to add related_name to access the set of rooms. Default related_name is '<fieldname>_set' (e.g. room_set).